# what is the best way to read an xml file, with lines containing data of the same type to python?

Tags: python, xml

I want to read an xml file, when every item in this file have the same attribute, and create a list of lists, each containing the attribute for every item.
the items look like this :[Xml example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXH5E.png)

thank you!

Comment: It is unclear what your specific problem is. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hey! thanks for trying to help
what I want to do, is to iterate through those items in the xml, and enter the relevant attributes of them into a list ( a list for each item)
and I didn't try anything specific yet, since I don't know how to read the items from the xml

Comment: Have you never worked with XML before? Did you search for similar questions? Perhaps you should start here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#tutorial

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Post the xml file (as **text**). Make sure its **valid**. Explain what is the expected output. Share your python code .

Comment: I am not allowed to post the XML unfortunately.. but mzjn advice helped me .thanks alot!